# How to switch to particular window out of 10 window if all have same title

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am facing a problem in my project. I have 10 window popups and 5 out of 10 have same title but I want to switch in specific window in selenium webdriver in Java.

Comment: What is specific about the window you are trying to switch to?

Comment: They all are popup window

Comment: But what is difference between them? You say title of 5 of them are same. But what is different in the page content among this 5? Then you can get the page source of the popup window and look for that unique thing. Or when opening the desired popup get and store the window handle to switch later on.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper ,  It worked...Thanks Juherr and JeffC for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

You try to switch to particular window by switching to a particular window by matching window URL, try following:

```
    Set <String> allHandles= driver.getWindowHandles();

    for(String curr : allHandles){

        driver.switchTo().window(curr);

        if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("Required URL")){

            break;
        }

    }
```

`Required URL` is url of the window you want to switch to

Comment: i Agree with your solution...but if all are popup window and we cant see the url , Any solution?

Comment: Yes then you can look for a particular element inside that window instead of a URL

Comment: Thanks kushal bro , it really helped me